# Magento 2 -Admin Grid Select filter with comma separated values

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent, filter, select

I have created a custom admin grid in my module. It contains a customer group column and it has a select filter. The column values are comma separated groupIds. When I filter the grid based on customer groups, it always show empty result for comma separated values. If the column has one value, then it is working fine.

[image]

Here is my code

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd"> 
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">attributerule_customergroup_listing.attributerule_customergroup_listing_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">attributerule_customergroup_listing.attributerule_customergroup_listing_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">attributerule_columns</item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Item</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
<dataSource name="attributerule_customergroup_listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">RuleGridDataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">attributerule_customergroup_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">rule_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">rule_id</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>       
</dataSource>
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
    <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
    <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
     <filters name="listing_filters" />           

    <paging name="listing_paging"/>
</listingToolbar>
<columns name="attributerule_columns">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">rule_id</item>
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">attributerule_customergroup_listing.attributerule_customergroup_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
            </item>
        </item>
            <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">attributerule_customergroup_listing.attributerule_customergroup_listing.productqa_columns_editor</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">attributerule_customergroup_listing.attributerule_customergroup_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root }</item>
                </item>
            </item>
    </argument>
    <selectionsColumn name="ids">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">rule_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </selectionsColumn>
    <column name="rule_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

    <column name="attribute_code">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Attribute Code</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>   
    <column name="customer_groups">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Company\Attributerule\Model\Source\Groups</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Groups</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column> 
    <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Company\Attributerule\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\RuleActions">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">rule_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </actionsColumn>
</columns>
```

Company\Attributerule\Model\Source\Groups.php

```
 class Groups implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    protected $customerGroupCollection;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customerGroupCollection
    ) {
         $this->customerGroupCollection = $customerGroupCollection;

    }
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $options = $this->customerGroupCollection->toOptionArray();
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Here is the database table structure

[image]

Please help me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below code in your Collection Class

```
public function addFieldToFilter($field, $condition = null)
{
    if ($field === 'customer_groups') {
        $conditionSec = ['like' => '%'.$condition['eq'].'%'];
        return parent::addFieldToFilter($field, $conditionSec);
    }
    return parent::addFieldToFilter($field, $condition);
}
```

Comment: it's not working for me